# How can I specify the correct list for my JQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two dropdown list in my view and I’m attempting to put one of them into an array.  The first dropdown list is named ‘listOfDays’ and the second one is ‘instructorString’.  For some reason the code retrieves text from both lists and put them in the array.  How can I specify the correct list for my JQuery array?  Here’s the script. Thanks for any help.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var trial = $('#instructorString').val();

            $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
                var checkList = new Array();
                $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                        checkList.push($(this).val());

                    }
                    else
                        checkList.push('unchecked');
                });
                alert(checkList);
            });




        });
```

Comment: instead of `$("select option:selected")` you need to use the id or class of the correct list... `$("select")` will select all drop downs

Comment: Can you also post sample of your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the ID of the select you need ..and you don't need `is(:selected)` part since your selector  `option:selected` selects all the option that is selected only..

```
$('#saveBtn').click(function () {
            var checkList = new Array();
            $("#corectSelectID  option:selected").each(function () {
               // if ($(this).is(':selected')) { <---//you don't need this as the selector selects only selected option
                    checkList.push($(this).val());

            });
            console.log(checkList);
        });
```

if you need the unchecked value in the array then select all option in the selector

```
  $('#saveBtn').click(function () {
            var checkList = new Array();
            $("#corectSelectID  option").each(function () {
               if ($(this).is(':selected')) 
                    checkList.push($(this).val());
               else
                    checkList.push('unchecked');

            });
            console.log(checkList);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only selecting selected options, so it makes no sense to check `is(':selected')`, as they all will be selected. To select all options and push different values based on the state :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var trial = $('#instructorString').val();
     $('#saveBtn').on('click', function () {
         var checkList = [];
         $("select[name='listOfDays'] option").each(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                 checkList.push( this.value );
             } else { // you where missing brackets
                 checkList.push('unchecked');
             }
         });
         //alert(checkList); You can't alert an array
         console.log( checkList )
     });
});
```

To select a `select` based on name, you'd do `$("select[name='listOfDays'] option")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("select option:selected")`

try  `$('select.Class_of_Correctlist ')`

`$("select option:selected")` will select all dropdown options which are selected.

```
$("select.correctList option").each(function () { 
              //correctlist is the class for the correct drop down
             if ($(this).is(':selected')) {
                 checkList.push( this.value );
             } else { //
                 checkList.push('unchecked');
             }
         });
```